# Alternatives to a 300 value nested IF formula within Excel

Tags: excel, if-statement

I receive Excel formatted returns from a DB (I have no control over) that present as in the pic below. I have to compile a 500 row report removing `Site Code` and replacing with the `Site Name`, in addition to adding the corresponding `City` and `State` in Excel. Rather than writing out an IF statement 300 times over for each value, what are the alternatives? I'd like to select the entire `Site Code` column, match it to the `Name`, and match it to the `City` and `State`.

I can work out an IF statement for `Site`, `City`, and `State`, and add nested IF statements, but writing it out 300 times X 3 is not the way to go. Example: `=IF(C3=F3, G3, IF(C3=F4, G4...))`

I cannot find a way to select the entire F column and match it the the G column. I've tried `F1:F300` etc. but cannot get it to work.

Any help is appreciated. If I'm looking for a different function let me know, I'd gladly do the research before posting again.

[Sample Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yw92g.png)

Comment: Look into `INDEX` and `MATCH` functions. You could start with a search for 'Index AND Match'. You'll find plenty of examples here (on SO), as well as elsewhere.

Comment: Your Site Code List as duplicate Sites (RR45).  You'll also need to decide how you want to handle that.  You can also use `VLOOKUP` or `XLOOKUP` to return the appropriate values (assuming the duplicate site is a typo).  Please edit your question to show what you have tried, and what problems you have run into.  If you are having problems, please include the version of Excel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe C19 should read "RR45" not "Name 1". If this is the case then you can use a lookup formula (Vlookup, Xlookup(365 only), Match & Index), so that you can avoid typing a "If" 300 times. You should always try to avoid long nested formulas to minimize errors.

Here is a simple Vlookup solution:

In cell D18: =VLOOKUP(C3,$F$3:$I$300,3,0)
In cell E18: =VLOOKUP(C3,$F$3:$I$300,4,0)

Now apply the formula till the bottom of your table.

Comment: I was able to get results working with VLOOKUP and some additional research since I had to account for the possibility of duplicate entries and orders. Thank you!